# Combine two multidimensional arrays in one new array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

Here I have two multidimensinal arrays i need to create new array with combined data, i need to compare the "module_ids' from the first one with the key of the second array.And if i have the same value need to create the same first array but with all the QIDs included.

```
foreach($course_data as $k => $courses) {
    foreach($question_ids as $t => $questions) {    
        $course_data[$k]['module_ids'] =  $questions;   
    }
 }

[2]=>
  array(4) {
    ["Course_ID"]=>
    string(4) "205W"
    ["State_ID"]=>
    string(2) "AR"
    ["Trade_ID"]=>
    string(13) "Test"
    ["module_ids"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["QIDs"]=>
      string(94) "4310, 4311, 4312, 4313, 4314, 4315, 4316, 4317, 4318, 4319, 4320, 4321, 4322, 4323, 4324, 4325"
    }
  }
```

This is the $course_data var res

```
  array(4) {
    ["Course_ID"]=>
    string(4) "205W"
    ["State_ID"]=>
    string(2) "AR"
    ["Trade_ID"]=>
    string(13) "Test"
    ["module_ids"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        string(4) "2127"
        [1]=>
        string(4) "2128"
      }
    }
  }
```

this is the $question_ids variable result

```
 array(2) {
        [2127]=>
            array(1) {
                ["QIDs"]=>
                string(58) "4300, 4301, 4302, 4303, 4304, 4305, 4306, 4307, 4308, 4309"
        }
        [2128]=>
            array(1) {
              ["QIDs"]=>
              string(94) "4310, 4311, 4312, 4313, 4314, 4315, 4316, 4317, 4318, 4319, 4320, 4321, 4322, 4323, 4324, 4325"
        }      
    }
```

need to combine both of the arrays if i find a result(same module_ids from both of the arrays)
Should look something like this

```
 array(4) {
    ["Course_ID"]=>
    string(4) "205W"
    ["State_ID"]=>
    string(2) "AR"
    ["Trade_ID"]=>
    string(13) "Test"
    ["module_ids"]=>
      array(2) {
        [2127]=>
            array(1) {
                ["QIDs"]=>
                string(58) "4300, 4301, 4302, 4303, 4304, 4305, 4306, 4307, 4308, 4309"
        }
        [2128]=>
            array(1) {
              ["QIDs"]=>
              string(94) "4310, 4311, 4312, 4313, 4314, 4315, 4316, 4317, 4318, 4319, 4320, 4321, 4322, 4323, 4324, 4325"
        }      
    }
  }
```

Tried to use array_intersect to check for the values in both of the arrays but still not able to make it right.

How can I achieve this? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Why have both become the same in your example result? Doesn't seem to make much sense.

Comment: I need them both in one combined array where in the new one have the QIDs for the module_ids, the value from the first array is the same as the key from the second array.

Comment: a) that was known already, and b) doesn't explain why your example input data and output don't appear to match.

Comment: Can there be any module ids in the first one, that do not have a match in the second one? (Or vice versa, but that is probably less likely, I suppose, because your example did not even cover that case.)

Comment: The second array is a result from a query with the module_id from the first one, i just need to combine them and after that put the in a csv. I fixed the example code, sorry wrong copy paste its my first time :)

Comment: So you should not need more than `$myFirstArray["module_ids"] = $mySecondArray;` then ...?

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about now.

Comment: Like that I will just merge two arrays without combining them, they will be just all in one array. I tried something like $myFirstArray[$key]["module_ids"] = $mySecondArray; but  i have the same value for the $mySecondArray.

Comment: What "combining" are you even talking about here? _"I tried something like `$myFirstArray[$key]["module_ids"] = $mySecondArray;`"_ - what is `$key` supposed to be now? So your first array is not just what you have shown above? But that same structure _multiple_ times, grouped in another array - or what?

Comment: foreach($course_data as $k => $courses) {
    foreach($question_ids as $t => $questions) {
        $course_data[$k]['module_ids'] =  $questions;   
    }
 }
Tried something like this but have the same value for the $question of course - result

 [2]=>
  array(4) {
    ["Course_ID"]=>
    string(4) "205W"
    ["State_ID"]=>
    string(2) "AR"
    ["Trade_ID"]=>
    string(13) "Test"
    ["module_ids"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["QIDs"]=>
      string(94) "4310, 4311, 4312, 4313, 4314, 4315, 4316, 4317, 4318, 4319, 4320, 4321, 4322, 4323, 4324, 4325"
    }
  }

Comment: module_ids from course_data is the same value as the key from question_ids

Comment: That is hardly readable in comments, please add this to your question and format it properly.

Comment: You are right. Added in the question. Thank you.

Comment: I have no clue what you are trying to do with these nested foreach loops there. Together with what you have presented as your input data so far, I can't make any sense of this. Please provide a proper [mre] including the data, in _usable_ form (so either a `var_export`, or as JSON.)

Comment: Added some more explanation in the original question, I hope its more clear now, but let me know if I have any mistakes(want to improve myself). Thank you.

Comment: No, it is not really more clear. I still can't tell, whether your $course_data array is supposed to contain one course, or multiple. And if multiple, then it would still be unclear, what result you want for the other elements. Again: Please present a _proper_ [mre] of the issue - that means _executable_ code, including the example data in a form we can directly use via copy&paste.

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4f94dfcee619446fd1aa3849492b0cad3de03caa
Here you can see the data, also tried to do something but still can't figure it out how to acomplish my desired result.

Comment: There's ids in the `module_ids` now, that don't have a match in the keys of $question_ids now. Assuming that is oversight on your part, and will not occur with the actual data, you probably want something like this, http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8b427743421876186464f5945c2110b54eb3c786

Comment: In my code where I was working I was very close but in the same time far away.Works perfect.Thank you very much.